# How to control the width of a Google Chart when printing?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a Google Bar Chart. When viewing the chart on a narrow screen, like on a smartphone, if you print the page, the chart prints at the width of the device instead of at the width of the paper.

How can I make the chart print at the full width of the paper regardless of what device it's being viewed on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to resize a google chart is to re-draw it.

as such, this would require listening for the window's `'beforeprint'` event...

```
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', (event) => {
  chart.clearChart();
  chart.draw();
});
```

and you could use `'afterprint'` to reset...

```
window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {
  chart.clearChart();
  chart.draw();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve it, since the redrawn chart is still drawn at the size of the viewport. 

I think what I need is to tell it to draw the chart at a different size when it's printed.

Comment: try the edit above, clearing the chart will allow the container to resize before drawing again. I've done this before, but couldn't immediately find the code...

Comment: No dice. But I solved it thus:

I created a second set of Google Chart options, which I named `printable_options`. Those options have a hard-coded width for the chart container (roughly paper-sized). Then I used your code to redraw the chart before printing, but feeding it the `printable_options` instead of the normal ones:    `chart.draw(data, printable_options);`
Thanks for the help!